# Bring Dropdown Selection in-front of all DIVs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the link: http://is.gd/zzX2uH

Please select the dropdown box.
The last few options are hidden behind the divs.

If I target `.join-form` and remove `overflow: hidden` the page is blown out.

May you please help me solve this problem?

Thanks for your attention,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the following css

```
media="screen"
.join-form {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
index2.htmlmedia="screen"
.join-form {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
index2.htmlmedia="screen"
section {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

remove **`overflow: hidden`** in all these styles.  Increasing the `z-index` does not have any effect in you page when it is hidden completely.

Comment: @MaggewDotCom I'm glad being a part to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

your .join-form has `overflow:hidden` which is why it is not displaying. setting .join-form to `overflow:visible` does get your drop down to display but has side effects.

Comment: Thanks 2pha! I was able to remove .join-form .container margin-bottom: 25px and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

```
.yourClassOrID {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

that should work.

If for some reason it doesn't, give a position of absolute, relative, or fixed to the parent of your dropdown.

Comment: Why should it be 1?  maybe  he has something set to 2 so 1 would be behind it. Setting it to 999 would make sure it is in front of anything under 999.

Answer (score 1):

Set the z-index of the dropdown to a value higher than that of the div

Comment: The z-index to ".join-form .container" is already 999. Which specific div do you recommend I target with Firebug?

Comment: try to set dd-select z-index higher than ".join-form .container"